# How can we formalize a game where each player is a program having access to opponent's code?

Tags: coq, applications, proof-assistant

How can we define in a proof assistant (eg., Coq) a notion of a 2-player game, where each player is a program that has access to the opponent's source code?

**Background:** In Open Source Game Theory, we think about bots that reason about each other (prove theorems), knowing the other's source code. I would like implement such bots in a proof assistant, if possible. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.07006.pdf, Open Problem 4)

What I have in mind would looks like this:

```
Inductive outcome := Cooperate | Defect.
(*  Dupoc is short for Defect Unless Proof of Cooperation   *)
Definition Dupoc (n:N) (bot2 : N -> bot -> outcome) : N -> bot -> outcome :=
    'try for n steps to find a proof that bot2 n self = Cooperate, if found':
        return Cooperate
    else
        return Defect.
```

The point is that we want to run the agents together with each other as input:

```
Definition game n1 bot1 n2 bot2 := (bot1 n1 bot2, bo2 n2 bo1).
```

Of course, the type `bot` does not exist as I have written it. Is there a way to actually make this happen?

The other problem is that the bot's function is trying to find a proof and returning a bool that reflects the success. Is this possible in some proof assistant? The proof assistant would have to have access to its own inner workings somehow, which seems hard.

I think I could solve the problem by having a Coq implementation in Coq.

Then I could have, like in the paper:

```
Inductive CoqTokens := ...
Definition BotExpression := ... (* A valid expression for a Bot *)
Class Bot := {
    play : BotExpression -> outcome,
    source : BotExpression (* This should be the source code for 'play' in our Coq-in-Coq implementation *)
}.
Definition game bot1 bot2 := (bot1.play bot2.source, bot2.play bot1.source).
```

But this seems very much work if it is possible. The Coq implementation in Coq still needs to contain everything about proofing. And I am not sure if it actually solves the problem.

Comment: I’m having trouble finding your question.

Comment: Lean 4 is implemented in Lean 4, so I think that would already supply a lot of the meta language needed for a system like yours.  There is also a Coq-in-Coq project you could look at.  Finally, projects that boot strap a theorem prover by proving the correctness of it’s implementation might also have the technology needed.  CakeML and MetaMath Zero come to mind.  But of course, I think what you are suggesting is very theoretical and cutting edge.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is something like “how can we define in a proof assistant (eg. Coq) a notion of game, where each player in the game has access to the other's code ?”. Is this correct?

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand Yes this is correct, I will add this to the post as the first Question. Thanks for distilling the essence.

Comment: Where can we see the syntax of the programs that the bots are written in? Is there a standard? If there is no standard, what are we supposed to do?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ideally the bots should be written in the functional part of the proof assistant itself. They should be able to prove things about each other's behavior. And finally, we want to prove things about the game. But my Intuition could be wrong. Do you think there is another way of doing it?

Comment: Just to be clear, if all the bots need to do is *see* the other’s code, then this can be done easily in any programming language.  But if one ants to prove something about the other program, then it becomes trickier.

Comment: Why do the bots "need" to prove anything? They just need to compute their moves, right? Could you give a scenario where it is important for a bot to actually produce a proof?

Comment: There is something called a "hyperfunction" which is the fixpoint of $F_{a,b}(x) = (x \to a) \to b$. Its game semantics is sort of like what you describe.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The whole point is to study the behavior of bots that know each other's source code and reason about their behavior. In this case, the reasoning is proving things. The bot returns Cooperate only if it can prove that its opponent also cooperates.

Comment: One difficulty here is one of *meta* vs *object* level (or, as computer scientist call it, *shallow* vs *deep* embedding): both your bots and the proofs they manipulate can be either Coq functions/proofs or representation of code/proofs inside Coq. You seem to want to use the first, even if this means you have to deal with some form of quotation. Indeed, this lets you use all the power of Coq to define your bots, but it is unclear to me that this is something you need or want. Having a poorer language for bot definition and proofs would make it much easier to reason on them.

Comment: A really cooperative robot would provide a proof that it is cooperative. Checking that a proof is valid is a lot easier than finding it.

Comment: The circularity here is confusing me. If both are using dupoc, then there’s no way to correctly prove cooperation is inevitable, because both defecting is a possible solution? Of course, either could force the other to cooperate by unconditionally cooperating, but then wouldn’t be using dupoc itself…

Comment: @DanielMGessel Yeah it's confusing. If you want to know the argument for why Dupoc cooperates I recommend reading the paper, it's really interesting. It's because of a variant of Löb's theorem.

Comment: I started on the paper and am thankful the authors recognize their results are not intuitive! Make me feel just a little less dumb!

Answer (score 9):

As you found out, the usual technique to solve this kind of difficulty is to introduce a notion of "code" (what you called `BotExpression`), which expresses the behaviour of your bot. Once you are happy with your codes, you can in a second time define a "decoding" function, something which takes in a code and spits out the expression, but this time as an actual Coq function. Taking the notations from your question, this means that you should be able to *define* a function that takes in `source` and outputs `play`. Note that to do this you *do not* have to reify all the syntax of Coq. Indeed, the actions available for your bots can probably be defined with a set of primitives smaller than full-fledged Coq. This lets you avoid the problem of using some form of self-description of the meta-language (which are *very* complicated beasts).

Similarly, you might also want to have such an encoding for proofs, again because your bots need to manipulate "concrete" data rather than meta-proofs in the ambient theory. Regarding formalization of logic, and also to give you ideas on the general code/decoding setting, you might want to give a look at eg. [this library formalizing first-order logic](https://github.com/dominik-kirst/coq-library-undecidability/tree/fol-library/theories/FOL).

Finally, there is a second issue you might stumble upon, either in the definition of your decoding function, or that of a play, which is related to the definition of functions in Coq. Indeed, as Coq lets you only define total/terminating functions, quite a lot of things with a "self-recursive" flavour are not definable as functions, as they would lead to non-terminating behaviour. In such a case, a standard solution is to replace the type `A -> B` by the type `A -> B -> Prop`, ie. replace an actual function by its graph. This avoids termination issues, and also determinism: since you do not encode a game as a function, you can have multiple choices to move on. Moreover, if you define your relation as an inductive one, you can reason by induction on it, which is probably the kind of reasoning principles you will be after.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a theoretical way you could do this in Lean 4.  The key is that you can prove stuff about pure code in Lean.  Lean's [`Declaration`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Declaration.html#Lean.Declaration) and [`Expr`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Expr.html#Lean.Expr) datatypes are pure code I believe, so a lot of work is done for you.  Type checking, however, while implemented in Lean 4, is not pure (or I don't think it is), so you would have to write a pure type checker.  Automation would also be a lot of work.

````
import Lean

inductive Outcome
| Cooperate
| Defect

-- A bot is a pure Lean fuction which takes in it's
-- own declaration and that of its opponent to produce an Outcome.
def Bot := Lean.Declaration -> Lean.Declaration -> Outcome

-- Pure code to run the game
def runGame (bot1 bot2 : Bot) (bot1Decl bot2Decl : Lean.Declaration) : Outcome × Outcome :=
  (bot1 bot1Decl bot2Decl, bot2 bot2Decl bot1Decl)

-- -----------------
-- Code needed to build the bots

-- Pure code for checking that a proof expr has the desired type expression.
-- Since type checking in Lean is undecidable, we add a timeout.
-- This code doesn't currently exist in this pure form but it could.
-- Just rewrite enough of the Lean kernel code using pure code and a timeout.
def checkProof (proof : Expr) (expectedType : Expr) (timeout : Nat) : Bool := sorry

-- Pure code for generating the expression
-- `selfBot selfDecl otherDecl = Outcome.Cooperate`
--I don't think this would be hard to write in a pure form.
def cooperateExpr (selfBotDecl otherDecl : Lean.Declaration) : Expr := sorry

-- My cooperate bot
def coorperateBot (selfBotDecl otherDecl : Lean.Declaration) : Outcome := Outcome.Cooperate

-- My bot which sees if the opponent is a simple coorperate bot
def checkIfOpponentIsCooperateBot (selfBotDecl otherBotDecl : Lean.Declaration) : Outcome :=
  -- the thing I'm trying to prove, namely `otherBot otherBotDecl selfBotDecl = Outcome.Cooperate`
  let oppCoopExpr : Lean.Expr := cooperateExpr otherBotDecl selfBotDecl
  -- try the simplest proof, namely `rfl`
  let proof : Lean.Expr := Lean.reflExpr oppCoorExpr  -- not correct code but this can be done
  -- check if proof is valid
  if checkProof proof oppCoopExpr 100 then
    Outcome.Cooperate
  else
    Outcome.Defect

-- Build more complicated bots by extending the logic for
-- `let proof : Expr := ...`
-- one could even implement search procedures
-- however almost all of Lean's automation isn't pure code,
-- so one would have to rewrite it to be pure I believe


-- --------
-- Running the game with the IO monad

-- Unpure meta code to look up the bots declarations and run the game
def runGameIO (bot1 bot2 : Bot) (bot1Name bot2Name : String) : IO (Outcome × Outcome) := do
  let bot1Decl <- Lean.get_decl bot1Name  -- not correct code but this can be done
  let bot2Decl <- Lean.get_decl bot2Name  -- not correct code but this can be done
  return (runGame bot1 bot2 bot1Decl bot2Decl)

def Outcome.repr : Outcome -> String
| Cooperate => "Cooperate"
| Defect => "Defect"

def main : IO Unit := do
  -- run game
  let result <- runGameIO
    coorperateBot checkIfOpponentIsCooperateBot
    "coorperateBot" "checkIfOpponentIsCooperateBot"
  -- print result
  IO.println result.1.repr
  IO.println result.2.repr
```
````

Comment: Can you give me a resource where I can learn or infer how to write the pure type checker? E.g. It would be useful to have the unpure type checking implemented in Lean. I can't seem to find it in the GitHub repo.

Comment: @MatthiasGeorgMayer Sorry for the late answer.  I looked into it more and the Lean kernel code seems to be in [Lean.Meta.Basic](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Lean/Meta/Basic.html) however, I think that a lot of the kernel is still written in C++.  Also, you can look at external checkers written in Haskell (https://github.com/leanprover/tc) and https://github.com/gebner/trepplein (Scala) for Lean 3.  They haven't yet been translated to Lean 4.

Comment: I'll try to flesh out my answer more this weekend if I have time.  In particular, I think there are a few smaller considerations I didn't think though in my original answer.